# getline read text seperated before an UPPERCASE LETTER in C++

Tags: c++, string, getline

log.txt

```
AwBcDoFgAgHmLoCb
AwCcDoAgBgHmCoZb
GwDcFoFgAgNmOoBb
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

main()
{
    string output;
    int counter=0;

    ifstream readLog;
    readLog.open("log.txt");

    while(!readLog.eof())
    {
        getline(readLog,output);  //read string line by line from the log.txt 
        cout<<counter+1<<"*  "<<output<<endl;  
        counter++;
    }
}
```

OUTPUT

```
1*  AwBcDoFgAgHmLoCb
2*  AwCcDoAgBgHmCoZb
3*  GwDcFoFgAgNmOoBb
```

my questions comes in here, I know that if there's a delimiter between the string. We can use multiple

```
Aw:Bc:Do:Fg:Ag:Hm:Lo:Cb

getline(readLog,output,':');  //output: Aw
getline(readLog,output,':');  //output: Bc
getline(readLog,output,':');  //output: Do
getline(readLog,output,':');  //output: Fg
getline(readLog,output,':');  //output: Ag
getline(readLog,output,':');  //output: Hm
getline(readLog,output,':');  //output: Lo
getline(readLog,output);      //output: Cb
```

but right now without the delimiter between the TEXT. I want to read in the output before the UPPERCASE LETTER

```
Example: AwBc

I just want to read in Aw and Bc Seperately, how can I make it works?
Is there any code can be written like

getline(readLog,output,'<UPPERCASE LETTER FUNCTION>');
```

Output(*expected)

```
Aw
Bc
```

Sorry for the long question I made, cause I want people's who read and view more easy to understand. Thank you in advance for your answer given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either process the read text or use regular expression for splitting something like following :

```
const std::string s = "AwBcDoFgAgHmLoCb";

boost::regex words_regex("[A-Z][a-z]");

auto words_begin = 
    boost::sregex_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), words_regex);

auto words_end = boost::sregex_iterator();
```

Loop over groups using:

```
for (boost::sregex_iterator i = words_begin; i != words_end; ++i) {
    boost::smatch match = *i;                                                 
    std::string match_str = match.str(); 
    std::cout << match_str << '\n';
}
```

---

[***<sup>`Demo Here`</sup>***](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ebb60890ab3c1fec)

***<sup>Used Boost here but I think you can go for std::regex  (GCC 4.9)</sup>***

Comment: Down Voters, I'm here to learn too, so please leave off your ego and  mind to provide a valid reason. I'd be happy to correct it or even delete it if its totally incorrect.